# Chrome dev tools upper console automatically closes bottom console/cannot move to bottom/top

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have somehow managed, that my console tab is locked in Chrome dev tools and I am not able to open console in top windows simultaneously with bottom console. It automatically collapses the opposite console tab and I cannot even right click and move to bottom/top.

I think, I used some shortcut accidentally, but cannot find how to reverse this behavior.

[image: chrome dev tools problem]